# Why is the output of fixed width unsigned integer negative while unsigned integer output wraps around as expected?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

```
#include <iostream>

#define TRY_INT

void testRun() 
{
    #ifdef TRY_INT          //test with unsigned
    unsigned int value1{1}; //define some unsigned variables
    unsigned int value2{1};
    unsigned int value3{2};
    #else                   //test with fixed width
    uint16_t value1{1};     //define fixed width unsigned variables
    uint16_t value2{1};
    uint16_t value3{2};

    #endif

    if ( value1 > value2 - value3 )
    {
        std::cout << value1 << " is bigger than: " << value2 - value3 << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << value1 << " is smaller than: " << value2 - value3 << "\n";
    }

}

int main()
{
    testRun();

    return 0;
}
```

with unsigned integers I get:

```
1 is smaller than: 4294967295
```

with fixed width unsigned int, output is:

```
1 is smaller than: -1
```

My expectation was it would wrap around as well, does this have something to do with std::cout?

Comment: Whats the bit representation (2 complement) of -1 ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, 0xFFFFFFFF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is caused by **integral promotion**. Citing form [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> ...**arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments**, and integral promotions are automatically applied after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable.
>
> `unsigned char`, `char8_t` (since C++20) or `unsigned short` **can be converted to `int` if it can hold its entire value range...**

Consequently, if `uint16_t` is just an alias for `unsigned short` on your implementation, `value2 - value3` is calculated with `int` type and the result is also `int`, that's why `-1` is shown.

With `unsigned int`, no promotion is applied and the whole calculation is performed in this type.

---

In the latest online C++ Draft, see [[conv.prom/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#1):

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_­t`, `char32_­t`, or `wchar_­t` whose integer conversion rank is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned int` is equivalent to `uint32_t` and `unsigned short int` is equivalent to `uint16_t`.

Therefore, if you use `unsigned short int` instead of `unsigned int` you will get the same behavior as for `uint16_t`.

**Why do you get -1?**

Integral promotion will try to convert `unsigned short int` to `int` if `int` can hold all possible values of `unsigned short int`. On the other hand, if that is not the case, integral promotion to `unsigned int` will be performed.

Therefore the subtraction is most likely done in the type `int`, not `uint16_t`.